# Apache POI HSMF HTML body extraction from MSG not working

Tags: java, outlook, apache-poi, mapi, msg

[Tests with POI 3.13 20150929 as well as the (older) version included in the Apache Tika 1.10 jar.]

I have Outlook MSG files with HTML bodies, including with embedded images.

Creating an HSMF MAPIMessage from the MSG files succeeds and most information is available (subject, sender, etc.), but getHtmlBody() always returns null.

This is true for MSG files created by constructing a message in Outlook using the HTML body format option and saving it as MSG as well as with messages sent from Thunderbird in mime/multipart/mixed/related/etc. and received by Outlook.  Outlook Spy shows a correct HTML body property in _MailItem view, as well as a BodyFormat property of 2 (olFormatHTML).  The actual extracted RTF (via getRtfBody) starts with `{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\fromhtml1`.

A dump of MAPIMessage's main chunks and main chunk properties shows chunks for `PR_BODY` and `PR_RTF_COMPRESSED`, but no `PR_BODY_HTML`. The attachments seem to be correct: `PR_ATTACH_FLAGS=4` for embedded attachments, `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` is set, `PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG`, `PR_ATTACH_LONG_FILENAME`, etc.

Perhaps I have a fundamental misunderstanding here, as Outlook Spy's _MailItem interface also includes a `MAPIOBJECT`, which does not seem to have the HTML body nor any body format.

Any suggestsions what's wrong here?  The MSG files clearly do contain the HTML body.  Does HSMF not expose the whole MSG file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

MSG files do not usually contain `PR_HTML` property. The HTML is encoded inside the `PR_RTF_COMPRESSED` property.

Comment: Any suggestions for how to extract it would be greatly appreciated.  Getting the RTF is no problem, but the HTML is entwined pretty tightly in the RTF.

Comment: Try to use Redemption (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) - unlike OOM, it can be used from a service. Use RDOSession.GetMesageFromMsgFile, then read the RDOMail.HTMLBody property.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook seems to parse (and therefore change) an attached MSG or EML file, even though its attached as a file!  As a result, attached emails are not the same byte-exact version as the original attached file. (#too-helpful)

As Dmitry Streblechenko answered on this question, attached messages usually only have an RTF and/or plain-text chunk of the bodytext, so you have to convert the RTF back to HTML :( The RTF has a close facsimile of your original HTML at least.

There are a few ways to do this, the obvious option being Tika: org.apache.tika.parser.rtf.RTFParser